# backing up a realm db in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, backup, realm, dropbox

I'm trying to backup the realm database in the app to a cloud storage solution like Dropbox.

I'm currently using the react-native-fs to read the file in base64 and then upload it. All that works fine but when I try to restore it back the file seems corrupted (encryption message, even though it is not encrypted) which leads me to presume I'm doing something wrong.

Is there any specific best practices to back the realm database in react-native?

Cheers

Comment: Whats your restoring code look like?

Comment: import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
async function backup(): Promise<Action> {
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
Realm.close()
RNFS.readFile(Realm.path, 'base64')
.then((response) => {
      Dropbox.filesUpload({
        contents: response,
        path: BACKUP_PATH,
        mode: "overwrite",
        autorename: true}).then((response) => {resolve(BACKUP_PATH)
      }).catch((error) => {...})
    }).catch((error) => {...})
  })}

when downloading and opening the file manually from Dropbox it shows the error (sorry for the code formatting)

Comment: Your content is saved is base64 on dropbox server. Are you decoding it back from base64 before opening? And how are you reading the file?

Comment: I was decoding it manually for the testing and opening with _Realm Browser_ . Maybe it's the base64 itself? Is there any other preferred format? [react-native-fs supports utf8, ascii or base64 (bin)](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)

Comment: There was an issue with the manual de-coding. Base64 decoding through the realm library works fine :) Thanks for your support @while1